# Direct sum of even and odd functions make whole vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Let $V$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-Vector space. How would you show that, for $V_1$ being the set of even functions and $V_2$ being the set of odd functions, the following is true: $$V = V_1 \oplus V_2 $$

I know that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces, and understand how the only function that can be both even and odd is the zero vector.

I also came across a post with a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135833/proof-of-subspaces-of-odd-and-even-functions), but I don't fully understand the provided answer.

Comment: Which part you have trouble with?

Comment: What is $V$? The only question left is if $V_1+V_2=V$ in the first place.

Comment: V is the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
The trouble I am having here is showing how exactly that the direct sum of the set of odd and even functions gives the vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $V$ is supposed be the vector space of real-valued functions. What you are asking (as far as I can tell) is whether $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$, with $V_1$ and $V_2$ being the subspaces of even-valued and odd-valued functions.

For any function $f$, we can define $g(x) = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$ and
$h(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$. Then, $g$ is even, and $h$ is odd, and $f = g + h$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I was trying to ask in my above question. However, what I am struggling with is how I exactly show that the direct sum of the set of odd and even functions gives the vector space.

Comment: Well, to be technical, the direct sum is finite, so it is equivalent to the direct product. We are implicitly associating a function $f$ to the coordinates $(g, h)$ in $V_1 \oplus V_2$. Can you elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: I am having trouble with showing why $V_1 \oplus V_2 = V $ is true. After some further research, it's my understanding that the direct sum in this case would hold true if $V = V_1+V_2$ and $V_1 \cap V_2 = {0_V}$. Would I then need to show that any function can be written as the sum of an odd and even function, and that the only function that is even and odd is the function that maps to the zero vector?

Comment: The point of defining $g$ and $h$ was to show that any function is a sum of even and odd components, so we get a natural bijection between $V$ and $V_1 \oplus V_2$. I wouldn't say they are *equal*, but I would say we can effectively regard one as the other.

Comment: So when showing that the above is true, it is sufficient to say that any $f(x)$ can be written as $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$, where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are even and odd respectively, and that the only function that is even and odd is the one that maps to the zero vector.

Comment: Any function $f$ can be decomposed into even and odd components, and obviously given any pair of an even and an odd function we can identify it with their sum in $V$. As for the fact that the only function that is both even and odd is the one that maps to the zero vector, note that $f$ is even if $h$ is zero everywhere, and $f$ is odd if $g$ is zero everywhere. The only function $f$ for which both $g$ and $h$ are zero everywhere is the one the maps to the zero vector, and so it is the only function that is both even and odd.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very general phenomenon which is unrelated to even or odd functions. Let $V$ be a (say, real or complex) vector space and $T\colon V\to V$ be a linear operator, not equal to ${\rm Id}_V$, but with $T^2={\rm Id}_V$. Then the minimal polynomial of $T$ equals $p(t) = t^2-1$. Since this polynomial splits as $(t-1)(t+1)$, we necessarily have that $T$ is diagonalizable, with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, and $V = V_+ \oplus V_-$, where $V_+$ is the eigenspace associated to $1$ and $V_-$ is associated to $-1$. What's more, we can actually say what the decomposition of any $v\in V$ relative to this direct sum is: $$v = \frac{v+Tv}{2} + \frac{v-Tv}{2}.$$If one cannot guess the above, do it systematically: write $v= v_+ + v_-$ with $Tv_+ = v_+$ and $Tv_- = -v_-$. Then $$\begin{cases} v=v_++v_- \\ Tv = v_+ - v_-\end{cases} \implies v_+ =\frac{v+Tv}{2}\quad\mbox{and}\quad v_-=\frac{v-Tv}{2}.$$

Examples:

1. $V$ is the vector space of all functions $W \to \mathbb{R}$, where $W$ is any non-trivial vector space (in particular, we may take $W=\mathbb{R}$), and let $T\colon V\to V$ be defined as $T(f)(x) = f(-x)$. This fits the bill and one may write $$f(x) = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} + \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2},$$for all $f\in V$ and $x\in W$. So any function $W\to \mathbb{R}$ is uniquely expressed as the sum of an even function with an odd function. This works for complex-valued functions too.
2. $V$ is the space of all real $n\times n$ matrices, and $T\colon V\to V$ is the transposition $T(A) = A^T$. Then $$A = \frac{A+A^T}{2} + \frac{A-A^T}{2}$$says that every real $n\times n$ matrix can be uniquely expressed as the sum of a symmetric matrix with a skew-symmetric matrix.
3. $V$ is the space of all complex $n\times n$ matrices (regarded as a real vector space), and $T\colon V\to V$ is the conjugate-transposition $T(A) = A^\dagger = \overline{A^T}$ (warning: this is $\mathbb{R}$-linear but not $\mathbb{C}$-linear). Then $$A = \frac{A+A^\dagger}{2} + \frac{A-A^\dagger}{2}$$says that every complex $n\times n$ matrix can be uniquely expressed as the sum of a hermitian matrix with a skew-hermitian matrix.

Comment: What a splendid answer! Thanks for your contribution.